# Run biber from inside LaTeXian

Tags: biber, editors, latexian

I often use [LaTeXian](http://tacosw.com/latexian/) on Mac OSX 10.9 to edit and display documents.  Occasionally, I want to use the live preview option with bibliography content.  The program allows you to enable a run of `bibtex`, `makeindex`, or `makeglossaries`, followed by 1, 2 or 3 extra runs of `latex` at the end.  This process is great, so long as you are using `bibtex` for the backend of the bibliography.

Is there any good way to get LaTeXian to run `biber` instead of `bibtex`?  I'm happy to entertain command-line hacks as well any more clean methods.

Comment: The possible answer should be added also to [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/31416).

Comment: if you can get it to use `arara` then it'll be easy :)